# How can i allow actions with my GUI only when mouse hovers the GUI

Tags: user-interface, mouseover, autoit

I want to allow actions with my created GUI only when the mouse hovers the GUI. Now i can close my GUI by *ESC* but this should only be possible when i do a mouse hover the GUI.

- How can I do that?

In a hobby project of mine i try a little bit with micro gaming stuff. Now i would like to do something in Autoit to. The followed code is just a example. When you can give me some hints i will increase my GUI.

```
#include <GUIConstantsEx.au3>
#include <WindowsConstants.au3>

$hGUI = GUICreate("GameTryout", 500, 500, -1, -1)
$cEdit = GUICtrlCreateEdit("test", 20, 20, 200, 100)
GUISetState(@SW_SHOW, $hGUI)

While 1
    Switch GUIGetMsg()
        Case $GUI_EVENT_CLOSE
            GUIDelete($hGui)
            Exit
    EndSwitch
WEnd
```

- How can I avoid closing my GUI without being on the GUI with the mouse?

Thank you for your suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `MouseGetPos()` and `WinGetPos()` to check if mouse cursor hovers your GUI. `_isMouseOnGui()` should fit your requirement:

```
#include <GUIConstantsEx.au3>
#include <WindowsConstants.au3>

$hGUI = GUICreate("GameTryout", 500, 500, -1, -1)
$cEdit = GUICtrlCreateEdit("test", 20, 20, 200, 100)
GUISetState(@SW_SHOW, $hGUI)

Func _isMouseOnGui($hGui)
    Local $aMouse = MouseGetPos()
    Local $aGui   = WinGetPos($hGui)

    If $aMouse[0] >= $aGui[0] And _
       $aMouse[1] >= $aGui[1] And _
       $aMouse[0] <= $aGui[0] + $aGui[2] And _
       $aMouse[1] <= $aGui[1] + $aGui[3] Then
       Return True
    EndIf

    Return False
EndFunc

While 1
    Switch GUIGetMsg()
        Case $GUI_EVENT_CLOSE
            If _isMouseOnGui($hGui) Then
                GUIDelete($hGui)
                Exit
            EndIf
    EndSwitch
WEnd
```

Extend your GUI actions by just checking the window/GUI position and mouse position for future functions too.